# Concatenate several files

Tags: perl, concatenation

I need to concatenate 20 .txt files into one with a UTF-8 encoding. The 20 files are all in the same directory. 
Can you help me ?
I was thinking about something like that

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fichier = "*.txt";
    open(FIC,">>:encoding(UTF-8)", $fichier) o
    close (FIC);

<>;
```

Comment: `cat *.txt > combined_file.txt`

Comment: What is the current encoding used for the files? Why do you think you need Perl for this?

Comment: I need to use perl because it's the only language I know lol. And the current encoding is UTF8

Comment: So, if you are on a unixy system, use @HunterMcMillen's suggestion. On Windows, use `copy /b *.txt combined_file.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

If the input and the output have the same encoding, no need to go through the effort of decoding and re-encoding.

```
print while <>;
```

For example,

```
perl -e'print while <>' *.txt >combined_file.txt
```

or just

```
perl -pe1 *.txt >combined_file.txt
```

or just

```
cat *.txt >combined_file.txt
```

---

If you don't want the wildcard to be passed as an argument, you can use the following:

```
my @qfns = glob('*.txt');
```

You can then open each of those files in turn.

Comment: And maybe prepend `@ARGV = glob '*.txt';`.

Comment: Maybe `@ARGV ||= glob '*.txt'`? To make it more flexible

Comment: In `cmd.exe`, use `copy /b *.txt combined_file.txt`

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, I think you mean `@ARGV = glob '*.txt' if !@ARGV;`, but that would be quite unconventional. I recommend against it

Comment: @ikegami Yep, that was what I meant. This was only in the event that the script defaulted to globing all text files, I don't think that is a good idea either.